# Trouble logging on to 14.04.01

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I'm having problems getting past the login screen.

I downloaded the 32 bit ISO from the Ubuntu website. The PC previously used Vista, with 2G of Ram and a 500G HDD. Not sure about the processor, but since it was running Vista just fine last week, I'd assume it's capable of running Ubuntu.

The installation seems to go fine. I chose the option to replace Vista with 14.04.1, install, and hit "reboot" when it was finished. Then the Ubuntu loading logo comes up and stays there for hours till I come back and do a hard reset. It boots up to the login screen, but after entering my password the screen goes out. I put a link to an image of what it looks like below after I put in my password.

[Photo of screen on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX5EU.jpg)

Any idea how to fix this problem?